# Formal argument countability

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Show that if $X$ is non empty and countable then the following set is countable: $\{\{ x \} : x \in X \}$.

Now the way I did this is by defining $A$ map $f$ from the set to $X$ by $f(\{x\}) = x$  which is clearly injective and because $X$ is countable, the set is therefore countable.

How can this be generalized? Is it true to say that if I have a countable set $X$ and a collection of subsets of $X$, $U$ then $U$ is also countable?

Comment: People put descriptions on tags for a reason.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila , Hello there! May you please clarify what the issue is, please? I put second countable as a tag because the above argument is used crucial to showing that every countable discrete space is a 0 manifold (which is second countable as a topological space). Furthermore, I added set theory because I initially learned about countable and uncountable sets through a set theory class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A collection  of subsets of a countable set need not be countable. The collection of all subsets of $\mathbb N$ is uncountable. But the collection of all finite subsets of a countable set is countable.

Any disjoint collection  of subsets of a countable set is countable [see my comment below].

Comment: So when would a collection of subsets of a countable set be countable ( other than when it is finite?)

Comment: I don't think you can give  a simple sufficient condition for that.

Comment: What about if the elements in the collection are pair wise disjoint?

Comment: In that case the collection is necessarily countable. You can pick one element from each of the sets and get a one-to-one function from the collection into the given countable set.

Comment: that’s so helpful. Thank you so much. Just one more question, picking one element from each of the sets is possible by the axiom of choice, right?

Comment: That is right. Axiom of choice is required for this.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is countable and infinite then $U:=\wp(X)$ is not countable.

Answer (score 0):

Its at least true if the collection of subsets of $X$ you consider
contains only finite subsets.

Concerning the example you gave at the beginning i would  argue the following
way,

Since X is countable there is a sequence ${x_n}$ such that 
for $n\neq\ m$ follows  $x_{n}\neq\ x_{m}$

and for each $x$ in $X$ there is a natural number k with $x_{k}=x$.

We can define a sequence $y_{n}\ $ in  $\{\{x\},x\in X\}$ then,

by 
$y_{n}:=\{x_{n}\}$ and it follows that for each $y\in\ \{\{x\},x\in\ X\}$ there is a natural number
k with $y_{k}=y$ and for $n\neq\ m$ follows $y_{n}\neq\ y_{m}$.

A set is countable iff there exists a bijective mapping from the natural numbers 
into the set.

Comment: Thanks for that! I appreciate it! My work is correct though, right?

Comment: About your second question concerning the generalisation consider what the first poster Kavi Rama explained

Comment: Sorry i had to rewrite my first comment because i made a typo and couldn't edit anymore what i meant is that your argument is valid(as far as i can tell) since you basicly show that cardinality of Y is same or lesser than X by constructing an injective mapping